# Laravel 5.2 & Angular 2 CRUD Example

Tags: laravel, angular, laravel-5

I am new to Angular2 & want to integrate it into my existing Laravel App built with Laravel 5.2, I have searched for an efficient example with the same but no luck, Can any one help me with it?

I would like to have a basic CRUD example with Laravel 5.2 & Angular2[not the beta version].

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Angular 2 be used with Laravel 5.2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34919044/can-angular-2-be-used-with-laravel-5-2)

Comment: @GerardReches Thanks Gerard for pointing it out..! But I would like you to know that I have been through the link but that link does not have the same thing. I am searching for the CRUD with Angular2, while that link contains only integration part. Even the answers given in the link did not work for me.

Comment: Check this repo: [axiskafi/angular2-laravel5](https://github.com/axiskafi/angular2-laravel5)

Comment: @GerardReches let me check it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice would be to use Laravel and Angular decoupled as separate applications with the Angular front end just consuming the Laravel exposed services. You can achieve that by checking examples and tutorials dedicated for each in part (interfacing via JSON/XML/etc.).

Here are some repositories to exemplify such integration:

https://github.com/Nightwhistle/Laravel5-Angular2-Material
https://github.com/softdevelop/Laravel5.3-Angular2-CRUD-Demo
https://github.com/aayaresko/laravel-demo-app-extended
https://github.com/trungcheng/laravel5-angular2-chat-socket
https://github.com/VsevolodYA/laravel5-angular2-dashboard